# Number of columns not matching

Tags: r, matching, rbind

I'm trying to use the `rbind` function to create some data for a matching process, but I'm getting this error:

```r
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

I've checked and adjusted the order so they definitely match, but still getting the error. Any idea why?

This is my code:

```r
# Match on the data from the year before treatment, matching on counttotal and countbrown
matchData <-
  rbind(treat_firms_1year_prior[, -c(
    grep("year_int_tx", colnames(treat_firms_1year_prior)),
    grep("matchingyear", colnames(treat_firms_1year_prior)),
    grep("flag", colnames(treat_firms_1year_prior))
  )],
  control_firms_year_int_tx)
```

These are the column names:

```r
> colnames(treat_firms_1year_prior)
 [1] "investor"            "dealyear"            "totalUSD"            "counttotal"          "greenUSD"            "countgreen"         
 [7] "brownUSD"            "countbrown"          "signatory"           "treatment"           "firsttreat"          "matchingyear"       
[13] "country"             "region"              "yearest"             "strategy"            "capsources"          "historicfunds"      
[19] "eligible_treat_firm" "year_int_tx"         "flag"
```

```r
> colnames(control_firms_year_int_tx)
 [1] "investor"            "dealyear"            "totalUSD"            "counttotal"          "greenUSD"            "countgreen"         
 [7] "brownUSD"            "countbrown"          "signatory"           "treatment"           "firsttreat"          "matchingyear"       
[13] "country"             "region"              "yearest"             "strategy"            "capsources"          "historicfunds"      
[19] "eligible_treat_firm" "year_int_tx"         "flag"
```

Answer (score 1):

`rbind` requires the 2 dataframes to have the same number of columns.

Yours do not have the same columns as `treat_firms_1year_prior` is dropping 3 columns ("year_int_tx", "matchingyear", flag") and `control_firms_year_int_tx` is not.

You'll need to also drop them in `control_firms_year_int_tx`, or keep them in `treat_firms_1year_prior`.

```
matchData <-
  rbind(treat_firms_1year_prior[, -c(
    grep("year_int_tx", colnames(treat_firms_1year_prior)),
    grep("matchingyear", colnames(treat_firms_1year_prior)),
    grep("flag", colnames(treat_firms_1year_prior))
  )],
  control_firms_year_int_tx[, -c(
    grep("year_int_tx", colnames(treat_firms_1year_prior)),
    grep("matchingyear", colnames(treat_firms_1year_prior)),
    grep("flag", colnames(treat_firms_1year_prior))
  )])
```

Or

```
excludeColumns <- c("year_int_tx", "matchingyear", "flag")

matchData <-
  rbind(
    treat_firms_1year_prior[ , !(names(treat_firms_1year_prior) %in% excludeColumns)], 
    control_firms_year_int_tx[ , !(names(control_firms_year_int_tx) %in% excludeColumns)]
  )
```

Or

```
matchData <-
  rbind(treat_firms_1year_prior, control_firms_year_int_tx)
```